# Purpose of one-sided carrier suppression in DBM phase detector for cavity stabilizer

Tags: oscillator

I am trying to understand a circuit taken from the link below. In the article they use a double balance mixer as a phase detector.

I have simulated the DBM mixer as a phase detector, results are shown below.

As you can see in the schematics of the article shown below they suppress the high frequency tone before putting it into the DBM phase detector.

What is the purpose of putting one signal with suppressed RF tone and the other input with unsuppressed RF tone?

In my simulation the phase detector works perfectly when both tones has equal amplitude.

https://docdro.id/xfSUAwC

[image]

[image]

[image]